# Resizable fixed footer with absolute elements within it

Tags: html, css

I want to make my fixed footer resizable on my 320px viewport, together with the absolute elements inside it.

I manage to get the footer div resizable, but the elements inside it doesn't seems to stick within the footer div when i resize the windows.

Note: I'm trying to create a footer with a background image. This image have some clickable areas which i created using the unordered list.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="form.php" class="iframe shootme-link">Shoot Me</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href=" " target="_blank" class="facebook-link">Facebook</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href=" " target="_blank" class="tumblr-link">Tumblr</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href=" " target="_blank" class="instagram-link">Instagram</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href=" " class="mail-link">E-mail</a>

        </li>
    </ul>

</footer>
```

Here is my CSS Code:

```
footer{
    z-index:21;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:0;
    width:1280px;
    height: 426px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background:url(../images/layout/footer.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    pointer-events:none;
}

footer ul li {
    display: inline;
    width: 14%;

}

footer ul li img {
    border: none;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

footer ul li a.shootme-link{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:200px;
    left:1080px;
    width: 151px;
    height: 33px;
    background:url(../images/layout/shootme.png) bottom;
    pointer-events:auto;
    /* Hide the text. */
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0px;
}
footer ul li a.shootme-link:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
footer ul li a.facebook-link {
    position:absolute;
    width:33px;
    height:29px;
    bottom:40px;
    left:970px;
    pointer-events:auto;
    /* Hide the text. */
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0px;
}
footer ul li a.tumblr-link {
    position:absolute;
    width:33px;
    height:29px;
    bottom:40px;
    left:980px;
    pointer-events:auto;
    /* Hide the text. */
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0px;
}
footer ul li a.instagram-link {
    position:absolute;
    width:33px;
    height:29px;
    bottom:40px;
    left:1030px;
    pointer-events:auto;
    /* Hide the text. */
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0px;
}
footer ul li a.mail-link {
    position:absolute;
    width:33px;
    height:29px;
    bottom:40px;
    left:1055px;
    pointer-events:auto;
    /* Hide the text. */
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

I'm still very much noob in CSS3 so i hope someone could enlighten me on this and pardon for my bad English. Hope it's not that confusing. Thanks

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5JWG5/
Full screen fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5JWG5/embedded/result/

Comment: making a fiddle might help..!!

Comment: It's not unlisted list, it's unordered list. To your question, if you want to have the absolute position, you can only modify with JS/ CSS media queries. Else you could do with % sizes. I don't understand why your ul is absolute anyway...

Comment: here is the fiddle jsfiddle.net/5JWG5 and the full screen fiddle: jsfiddle.net/5JWG5/embedded/result Basically i just want to make the social media icons area on the bg image clickable. Kinda like the idea of image map. It works on the full screen fiddle, but it won't work on the smaller screen because the ul elements are not shifted together when the window is resized. Hope by now you kinda understand what i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I Hope this help you, first:

it's easier using divs instead of a list, so we can achieve the location of the elements better.

```
<footer>
    <div class="shootme-link">
        <a href="form.php"  class="iframe">Shoot Me</a>
    </div>

    <div class="social">
        <a class="facebook-link" href=" " target="_blank" >Facebook</a>
        <a href=" " target="_blank" class="tumblr-link">Tumblr</a>
        <a href=" " target="_blank" class="instagram-link">Instagram</a>
        <a href=" " class="mail-link">E-mail</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

as you can see, i also reduce the number of classes, instead using one for each element, now i'm using just one name it "social", this will be a Div box that will nest the link elements.

Then, we will point to the links inside that div to give them size and we will float all to the left. using `display: inline-block` and `text-align: left;` (you could also use `display: block;` and `float: left;` but the you should give them a margin)

this is the new CSS

```
footer{
  z-index:21;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width:1280px;
  height: 426px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background:url("http://jennisa.com/images/layout/footer.png") no-repeat right bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  pointer-events:none;
}


footer > .shootme-link {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:200px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 151px;
    height: 33px;
    background:url("http://jennisa.com/images/layout/shootme.png") bottom;
    pointer-events:auto;
    /* Hide the text. */
    text-indent: -999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

footer > .social {
    position: absolute;
    width: 163px;
    height: 32px;
    bottom: 46px;
    right: 163px;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

footer > .social > a {
    background-color: blue;
    width:33px;
    height:29px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    pointer-events:auto;
    /* Hide the text. */
    text-indent: -999px;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

there is [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3nZU/)

for the background size I use the attribute `cover` instead `100%` because this will kep the proportions of the image to cover all the div and also i positioned the image to the right, because is there where the elements are (the elements also are positioned `absolute` since the right.

you just delete `background-color: blue;` from the links (I used it to point the changes visually)

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what i want to achieve but been struggling for a week because of my outdated knowledge. Nested class on CSS is a new thing for me so i never thought to do that and use list instead. I learn new things today from you. Again thanks for all the hassle and a very clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure of what you're trying to do, i speak spanish, if that language works for you, you could explain better in it.

anyway, i think you could use `position: relative;` instead of `position:absolute;`.

"inline-block" has text capabilities, so you can use `text-align: center;` or use `display:block;` and float everything to the left.

but i don't see the point of "float" your elements if give them an absolute position.. may be you could use   jsfiddle to explain your point better with an example.

is not necessary to use `max-width: 100%;`you just put the width at 100% of the size and declare the minimun width size, for example "320px" and the div will not be smaller than this size.

Hope this help you :)

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5JWG5/ and the full screen fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5JWG5/embedded/result/
Basically i just want to make the social media icons area on the bg image clickable. Kinda like the idea of image map.
It works on the full screen fiddle, but it won't work on the smaller screen because the elements are not shifted together when the window is resized. Hope by now you kinda understand what i want to do.